# OpenLayers: Open popup when hovering vector, without closing it when mouse is over popup itself

Tags: popup, openlayers

I have a map with a vector layer showing features from GeoJSON. When I hover the feature, a pop-up shows up at the beginning of the linestring. But it is flickering, it appears and disappears. I guess the feature somehow gets deselected. Maybe popup gets in the middle between mouse and the feature so the condition of feature being hovered is no more fulfilled. How can I solve it? I want the pop up to be displayed when the mouse is over the feature, no matter if the popup is in the way.

I think it can be replicated even with example code: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/light-basic.html .

It happens even if my mouse is not directly over the white part of the popup.

It seems to me the problem is more severe in chrome than in firefox. Maybe this is not the problem of my code, but bug. If so, sorry for posting here.

[image: Flickering popup]

I am using foollowing code :

```
    layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("JOSM", {
                eventListeners: {
                    'featureselected': function(evt) {

                        var feature = evt.feature;
                        var detailsTextHtml = "";
                        var lines = feature.attributes.evaluations.split("\n");
                        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                            if (lines[i] !== "") {
                                detailsTextHtml += " <br> " + lines[i];
                            }
                        }
                        popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popup",
                                OpenLayers.LonLat.fromString(feature.geometry.getVertices()[0].toShortString()),
                                null,
                                "<div style='font-size:.8em'>Coefficient: " + feature.attributes.coefficient + "<br>Color:" + feature.attributes.color + "<br>Details: " + detailsTextHtml + "</div>",
                                null,
                                true
                                );
                        feature.popup = popup;
                        map.addPopup(popup);
                    },
                    'featureunselected': function(evt) {
                        var feature = evt.feature;
                        map.removePopup(feature.popup);
                        feature.popup.destroy();
                        feature.popup = null;

                    }
                },
                styleMap: styleMap,
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                projection: geographic,
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: "webresources/getJosmAspectsDetailed?startLon=" + document.getElementById('startLon').value +
                            "&startLat=" + document.getElementById('startLat').value +
                            "&endLon=" + document.getElementById('endLon').value +
                            "&endLat=" + document.getElementById('endLat').value + "&speed=17&comfort=0&quietness=0",
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
                })
            });
```

Comment: Try http://jorix.github.io/OL-FeaturePopups/examples/feature-popups.html is not a OL standard code.